# Problems with javascript settimeout function

Tags: javascript

I have a problem that i want to bind my `setTimeout`

```
$(document).click(function () {
    function aktivereSkift() {
        $(this).attr("src", "/lib/pictures/picA.png");
        setTimeout("$('.myImg').attr('src', '/lib/pictures/picB.png')", 3000);
    }

    $(".myImg").on("click", aktivereSkift);
});
```

The problem is that i can only get i to work with this, which is not working properly it changes all the images to picB.png... is there a way that i cant do some "binding" like i do with the first $(this).attr changer??

Comment: What's with all those blank lines? Anwyay, `setTimeout` should be called with a function as first argument. Start with that...

Comment: Why are you using `$(document).click()`?

Comment: @trincot Believe it or not, you actually _can_ pass a string of code to `setTimeout`.  It's not suggested, but it does work.  The code string gets ran via `eval()`!  So, while not recommended, it does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should not pass a string to `setTimeout`: this is bad practice. Pass a function, and make it an arrow function so that you can still refer to the same `this` as in the statement before it:

```
  function aktivereSkift() {
      $(this).attr("src", "/lib/pictures/picA.png")
      setTimeout(() => $(this).attr('src', '/lib/pictures/picB.png'), 3000);
  }
```

NB: it is strange that you put your code in a `$(document).click` handler.